# Трехмерный бфс на гриде

Tags: c++, графы

У меня есть трехмерный грид (грид - координатная плоскость) из 4 уровней, каждый уровень имеет размер n * m. Из каждой ячейки грида можно либо перейти в ту же самую, но на уровень ниже, либо на уровень выше. Так же каждая ячейка имеет от 0 до 4 дверей, ведущих соответственно в ячейки (x + 1, y, z), (x - 1, y, z), (x, y, z - 1), (x, y, z + 1), то есть только по своему уровню. Так же есть ячейки, из которых никуда нельзя перейти. Все операции перехода стоят 1. Необходимо запустить по гриду бфс. Пожалуйста, не пишите код, объясните общую идею (как писать обычный бфс я знаю).
Построение грида:

```
vector <vector<vector<char>>> gr(4, vector<vector <char>> (n + 2, vector <char> (m + 2)));
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; ++j){
            cin >> gr[0][i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j){
                if (gr[k][i][j] == '+'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = '+';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == '-'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = '|';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == '|'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = '-';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == '^'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = '>';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == '>'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = 'v';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == '<'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = '^';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == 'v'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = '<';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == 'L'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = 'U';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == 'R'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = 'D';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == 'U'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = 'R';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == 'D'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = 'L';
                }
                else if (gr[k][i][j] == '*'){
                    gr[k + 1][i][j] = '*';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Расшифровка символов:

```
«+» означает, что этот блок имеет 4 двери (в каждый из соседних блоков);
«-» означает, что этот блок имеет 2 двери — в соседний слева и соседний справа блок;
«|» означает, что этот блок имеет 2 двери — в соседний сверху и снизу блоки;
«^» означает, что этот блок имеет 1 дверь — в соседний сверху блок;
«>» означает, что этот блок имеет 1 дверь — в соседний справа блок;
«<» означает, что этот блок имеет 1 дверь — в соседний слева блок;
«v» означает, что этот блок имеет 1 дверь — в соседний снизу блок;
«L» означает, что этот блок имеет 3 двери — отсутствует дверь в соседний слева блок;
«R» означает, что этот блок имеет 3 двери — отсутствует дверь в соседний справа блок;
«U» означает, что этот блок имеет 3 двери — отсутствует дверь в соседний сверху блок;
«D» означает, что этот блок имеет 3 двери — отсутствует дверь в соседний снизу блок;
«*» означает, что этот блок является стеной и не имеет дверей.
```

Написал превращение этого в явный граф (спасибо человеку из комментариев). Теперь вроде можно запускать по нему обычный бфс. Только вот я сильно не уверен, что правильно преобразовываю в список смежности

```
//costil - трехмерный вектор, в котором пронумерованы все вершины
//вектор gr имеет размер 4 * (n + 2) * (m + 2), чтобы нигде не выходить за границы
vector <vector<int>> g(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k){
                switch (gr[i][j][k]){
                    case '+':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k + 1]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j + 1][k]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j - 1][k]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k - 1]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k - 1]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k + 1]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case '|':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j + 1][k]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j - 1][k]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case '^':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j - 1][k]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case '>':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k + 1]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case '<':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k - 1]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'v':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j + 1][k]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'L':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j + 1][k]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j - 1][k]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k + 1]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'R':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j - 1][k]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j + 1][k]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k - 1]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'U':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j + 1][k]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k + 1]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k - 1]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k + 1]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j - 1][k]);
                        g[j].push_back(costil[i][j][k - 1]);
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        if (i != 3){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i + 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        if (i != 0){
                            g[j].push_back(costil[i - 1][j][k]);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну варианта два. Первый: задать граф в явном виде - то есть присвоить каждой клетке грида уникальный номер и описать все переходы из нее любым удобным способом (вроде все предпочитают список смежных вершин), после чего можно запустить по графу самый обычный бфс. Второй: сделать обход по неявному графу. Тогда вам нужно для каждой клетки именно внутри бфс'а определить, в какие клетки доступен переход, после чего добавить их в очередь. Разницы особой нет, но второй способ оптимальнее по памяти, так как не нужно хранить все ребра - они вычисляются налету. P.S. Слышали про switch-case?

Comment: И я правильно понимаю - у вас действительно каждый из этажей имеет одинаковую "карту"? Тогда почти наверняка можно оптимизировать код, используя бфс только для одного этажа, а для всех остальных добавлять какую-то нужную вам операцию при переходе вверх-вниз.

Comment: EzikBro, это понятно, я собирался задавать граф в явном виде, тк по памяти лимит 256 мб, но речь о том, что нужно учитывать, что кратчайший путь может лежать через другие слои, те бфс должен идти не по одному конкретному слою

Comment: И нет, каждый этаж имеет не одинаковую карту, посмотрите внимательнее на ифы

Comment: Но согласно вводу вы считываете только первый этаж, после чего каждому из этажей присваивается та же самая карта. И я не понимаю, что вас беспокоит в том, что бфс должен идти не по одному слою. Если вы записываете граф в явном виде, то вы переводите его в обычный граф. Там нет никаких этажей внутри него, только вершины и ребра. У вас проблема с заданием этого явного графа по карте?

Comment: А еще важный момент - у вас граф неориентрированный? То есть если из одной клетки есть путь во вторую, то обязательно ли из второй есть путь в первую, или может оказаться так, что из вершины есть путь в стену?

Comment: граф неорентированный, я понял, как использовать тут обычный бфс, спасибо. Попробую написать

Comment: я отредактировал вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123922/discussion-between-ezikbro-and-verybadcoder).